# how to replace fragments tabs inside mainfragment by using button click

Tags: android

hey guys i'm sufferening to problem how to call tab fragments inside fragment.i am always click on  button show unfortunately app closed and in logcat show nullpointer exception.i implemented but gettting errror null object reference
                        Lead_Fragment Main fragment
                        in which define the code add all tabs in toolbar and show the view of mainfragment
              in which define the code add all tabs in toolbar and show the view of mainfragment
              in which define the code add all tabs in toolbar and show the view of mainfragment

```
                    package com.example.dashboard;
                    import android.app.Fragment;
                    import android.app.FragmentManager;
                    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
                    import android.content.Context;
                    import android.os.Bundle;
                    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
                    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
                    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                    import android.view.View;
                    import android.view.ViewGroup;

                    import com.example.admin.bdayevent.R;

                    public class Lead_Fragment extends Fragment implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener,Frgmentchangelistener {

                        private TabLayout tabLayout;
                        private ViewPager viewPager;
                        Context context;



                        @Override
                        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lead_fragment, container, false);
                            tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.leadtabLayout);
                            //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Step1"));
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Step2"));
                            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
                            //Initializing viewPager
                            viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.leadmain_container);
                            //Creating our pager adapter
                            Lead_Pager adapter = new Lead_Pager(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                            //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
                            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
                            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
                            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
                                {

                                }

                                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                                }

                                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                }
                            });
                            Lead_step1 fragment1 = new Lead_step1();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager =getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.leadmain_container, fragment1);
                            // fragmentTransaction.hide(Step1.this);
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            return view;
                        }

                        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
                        {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tab selected "+tab.getPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    //    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
                    //        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    //        if (addToBackStack)
                    //        {
                    //            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    //        }
                    //        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    //        transaction.commit();
                    //        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
                    //    }

                        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
                        {
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"tab unselected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
                        {

                        }
                        void switchFragment1(int target)
                        {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(target);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
                        {

                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.leadmain_container, fragment, fragment.toString());
                            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }
                    }
```

Lead_tab1 this is the first fragment which contain the form like registration page those values stored in sqlite db but when i cliked on button show the null object Rerference(nul pointer) this is the first fragment which contain the form like registration page those values stored in sqlite db but when i cliked on button show the null object Rerference(nul pointer)

```
                package com.example.dashboard;

                import android.app.Fragment;
                import android.app.FragmentManager;
                import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
                import android.content.SharedPreferences;
                import android.os.Bundle;

                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.EditText;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                import com.example.admin.bdayevent.R;
                import com.example.admin.bdayevent.Registration;

                /**
                 * Created by admin on 4/28/2016.
                 */
                public class Lead_step1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
                    EditText customername,customermobile,referncename;
                    Button nextbtn;
                    String MobilePattern = "[0-9]{10}";
                    SharedPreferences lead_pref = null;
                    Lead_Fragment lead_fragment;
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                    {
                        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lead_step1, container, false);
                        customername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_customername);
                        customermobile = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_mobileno);
                        referncename = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_referencename);
                        nextbtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.leadnext);
                        nextbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
                        return view;
                    }
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if (customername.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            customername.setError("please enter name");

                        }
                        else if (customermobile.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            customermobile.setError("please enter 10 digit mobileno");

                        }
                        else if (referncename.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            referncename.setError("please enter refernce name");

                        }
                        else if(customermobile.getText().toString().matches(MobilePattern) == false)
                        {

                            customermobile.setError("plz enter 10 digit mobile number");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((Lead_Fragment) getParentFragment()).switchFragment1(2);
                            String Lead_name=customername.getText().toString().trim();
                            String Lead_Mobile=customermobile.getText().toString().trim();
                            String Lead_Reference=referncename.getText().toString();
                            System.out.println("value of leads"+Lead_name+":"+Lead_Mobile+":"+Lead_Reference);
                            lead_pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("lead_pref",getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = lead_pref.edit();
                            editor.putString("key_Lead_name", Lead_name);
                            editor.putString("key_Lead_Mobile", Lead_Mobile);
                            editor.putString("key_Lead_Reference", Lead_Reference);
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Lead_tab2, this is the second fragment which contain the form like registration page similar to first fragement which in define 3 editetext.

```
                import android.app.AlertDialog;
                import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
                import android.app.Fragment;
                import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
                import android.content.Intent;
                import android.content.SharedPreferences;
                import android.os.AsyncTask;
                import android.os.Bundle;
                import android.view.Gravity;
                import android.view.LayoutInflater;
                import android.view.View;
                import android.view.ViewGroup;
                import android.widget.Button;
                import android.widget.DatePicker;
                import android.widget.EditText;
                import android.widget.TimePicker;
                import android.widget.Toast;

                import com.example.admin.bdayevent.Database;
                import com.example.admin.bdayevent.R;

                import java.text.ParseException;
                import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
                import java.util.Calendar;
                import java.util.regex.Matcher;
                import java.util.regex.Pattern;

                public class Lead_step2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
                    EditText eventname, eventlocation, eventdate, eventtime;
                    Button submit_btn;
                    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
                    private static final String TIME24HOURS_PATTERN =
                            " (([0-1]?[0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9] ";
                    private Pattern pattern;
                    private Matcher matcher;
                    SharedPreferences Lead2;
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lead_step2, container, false);
                        eventname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_eventname);
                        eventlocation = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_location);
                        eventdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_date);
                        eventtime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_time);
                        submit_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.lead_submitbtn);
                        eventdate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                if (hasFocus) {
                                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                                    eventdate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                                }
                                            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                                    datePickerDialog.show();
                                } else {
                                    //datePickerDialog.
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        eventtime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                if (hasFocus) {
                                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                                    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                                    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                                      int minute)
                                                {

                                                    boolean isPM = (hourOfDay >= 12);
                                                    eventtime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", (hourOfDay == 12 || hourOfDay == 0) ? 12 : hourOfDay % 12, minute, isPM ? "PM" : "AM"));
                                                }
                                            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                                    timePickerDialog.show();
                                } else {
                                    // Hide your calender here
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        submit_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
                        return view;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        if (eventname.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            eventname.setError("please enter eventname");

                        } else if (eventlocation.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            eventname.setError("please enter eventlocation");

                        } else if (eventdate.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            eventdate.setError("please enter evendate");
                        } else if (eventtime.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            eventtime.setError("please enter Eventtime");
                        }
                        else if (validateTime(String.valueOf(eventdate.getText())))
                        {
                            eventdate.setError("please enter Valid Date");
                        }
                        else if(validateDate(String.valueOf(eventtime.getText())))
                        {
                            eventtime.setError("please enter Valid Date");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Welcome to leadgenration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                           // ((Lead_Fragment) getParentFragment()).switchFragment1(2);
                            new Lead_generation().execute();
                        }
                    }
                class Lead_generation extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
                {


                       protected void onPreExecute()
                    {
                        //System.out.println("value of user is preexecute:" + User_mobile + "" + User_password);
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),
                        AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
                        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Authenting....plz wait");
                        progressDialog.show();
                    }

                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {
                         if(Send_Lead())
                         {

                         }

                        return false;
                    }
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if(result==true)
                        {
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Lead Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not add Lead",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                }

                    public boolean Send_Lead()
                    {

                        Lead2=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("lead_pref", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String Lead_Cutom_name = Lead2.getString("key_firstname","");
                        String Lead_Custom_contact = Lead2.getString("key_lastname","");
                        String Lead_Custom_reference = Lead2.getString("key_user_org","");
                        String Lead_Eventname=eventname.getText().toString().trim();
                        String Lead_Eventlocation=eventlocation.getText().toString().trim();
                        String Lead_EventDate=eventdate.getText().toString().trim();
                        String Lead_EventTime=eventtime.getText().toString().trim();
                System.out.println("value of all leads"+Lead_Cutom_name+" "+Lead_Custom_contact+" "
                                +Lead_Custom_reference+" "+Lead_Eventname+" "+Lead_Eventlocation+" "+Lead_EventDate+" "+Lead_EventTime);
                if(Database.ADD_Lead(getActivity(),Lead_Cutom_name,Lead_Custom_contact,Lead_Custom_reference,Lead_Eventname,Lead_Eventlocation,
                        Lead_EventDate,Lead_EventTime))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                        else
                {
                    return false;
                }

                    }
                    public boolean validateTime(final String time)
                    {

                        matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
                        return matcher.matches();

                    }

                    public boolean validateDate(String date)
                    {
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        try {
                            sdf.parse(date);
                            return true;
                        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

LOCATFILE
this is the logcat file show background processing also show the any type of error occur in  your project

```
05-11 06:16:53.858 13059-13059/com.example.admin.bdayevent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.bdayevent, PID: 13059
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dashboard.New_dashboard cannot be cast to com.example.admin.bdayevent.Registration
at com.example.dashboard.Lead_step1.onClick(Lead_step1.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: please guys i need your help

Comment: please add the stacktrace to your question. It might be helpful

Comment: Iulian Popescu sir added locat file

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
put one container or use the existing container and make a fragment transaction there when you click the button. like this

```
NEWFragment new_fragment = new NEWFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = (context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, new_fragment, new_fragment.toString());
transaction.addToBackStack(new_fragment.toString());
new_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: sir added locat file...that's show null object reference.when i was use this code with activity work fine but after that use with fragment its not working

Comment: by using your(jithu sir) after pressing button click show the black page on both tab.....Fragment->Tab1(Tab1 contain button to go to tab2)->Tab2(Tab2 contain submit buton and store record in db)

Comment: ((Lead_Fragment) getParentFragment()).switchFragment1(2);  try to remove this,actually why you need this? for viewpage indicator change?

Comment: to solve the black screen try like this 

// fragmentmaganer.addToBackStack() // dont include this for your fragment

Comment: yeah..sir but after remove that code and paste you code but its show black page on both tab

Comment: after doing show error....after click on tab2....Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference

Comment: transaction.addToBackStack(new_fragment.toString());

you need to remove only  this line from my answer. i think u done something wrong.

Comment: no sir..again show error afte click on tab2 and swap Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:1018)

Comment: but sir that code working fine with activity with add toolbar and tab fargment...i already implement

Comment: put your container in lead_step1 and on button click remove this code 
((Lead_Fragment) getParentFragment()).switchFragment1(2); 
 add this code 
                   NEWFragment new_fragment = new NEWFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = (context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.container, new_fragment, new_fragment.toString());
                    new_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

Comment: no sir its not working......show this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:1018)